# Chrome won't load Create-React-App but Firefox will?

Tags: reactjs, google-chrome, create-react-app

Chrome all of a sudden stopped loading any of my react projects via localhost:3000 or any other port. Firefox works fine. Postman works fine as well. Only thing different is I'm on hotel wifi but the strange thing is I've been on it for over 2 days and it stops working all of a sudden? Anybody insight or experience into such a thing? I'm getting this error:

This page isn’t working
If the problem continues, contact the site owner.
HTTP ERROR 400

Comment: Did you ever fix this? I have exactly the same problem

Comment: @DarrenSweeney it started working when I got home. I think the hotel wifi is doing something to dns that Chrome does not like.

Comment: Interesting, I have the same problem, but works fine on my friends machine (different location) and on my other MBP (different location), and works fine in incognito mode